# Continuously update a QML LineSeries ChartView with a data model from C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qabstractitemmodel

I have a ChartView in QML I'm trying to update from a data model in C++, however, I'm running into certain issues where I can't seem to figure out a way to update the LineSeries properly.

My Sample QML Code looks like:

```
ChartView {
    id: dataChartView
    animationOptions: ChartView.NoAnimation
    theme: ChartView.ChartThemeDark
    antialiasing: true
    Layout.fillHeight: true
    Layout.fillWidth: true

    ValueAxis {
        id: axisXdata
        min: dataManager.xMin
        max: dataManager.xMax
    }

    ValueAxis {
        id: axisYdata
        min: 0
        max: 1
    }

    LineSeries {
        id:  dataLineSeries
        name: "Angle"
        axisX: axisXdata
        axisY: axisYdata
    }

    VXYModelMapper {
        id:  dataModelMapper
        model: dataManager.dataModel[data]
        series: dataLineSeries
        firstRow: 1
        xColumn: 0
        yColumn: 1
    }
}
```

The underlying model is a QAbstractTableModel that looks like this:

```
class DataModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum{
        NameRole,
        ValueRole
    };

    explicit DataModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    void setMaxSize(int maxSize);
    int maxSize() const;
    Q_INVOKABLE void addData(const QPointF& point);

     public:
         void handleNewData(const QPointF& point);
    
    private:
        QVector<QPointF> m_data;
        int m_ModelMaxSize;
    
    signals:
         void newDataAdded(const QPointF& point);
    
    
    };
```

and the relevant `addData()` function simply just pushes the Point into the `m_data` vector

```
void MsclDataModel::addData(const QPointF &point)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    m_data.push_back(point);
    endInsertRows();
}
```

I then have another class called `DataManager` which runs a function in another thread and just adds points to the data model

```
void DataManager::GeneratePoints()
{
    setXMin(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toMSecsSinceEpoch()); // for the min and max on the horizontal axis
    for(double t=0 ; ; t+=1)
       {
           double y = (1 + sin(t/10.0)) / 2.0;

        // many data models are required
           for(const auto& model : m_Models)
           {
               auto time = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toMSecsSinceEpoch();
               setXMax(qMax(m_xMax, time));
               model->handleNewData(QPointF(time, y));
           }
           std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
}
```

My issue is with this method and with the number of models I have, the application slows to a crawl and crashes eventually after about a minute or so. I've tried to constrain the `addData()` function to only show the latest 500 points by using something like this:

```
void DataModel::addData(const QPointF &point)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    if(m_data.size() == 500)
    {
        m_data.erase(m_data.begin());
    }
    m_data.push_back(point);
    endInsertRows();
}
```

However, my output looks something like:
[image: DataModel stops updating] where the data model just stops updating after the 500th point.

I've also tried using a List to pop after max size of the list has been reached but the output is still the same. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just as a side note, you can use [pop_front()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlist.html#pop_front) or [removeFirst()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlist.html#removeFirst) to remove the first element in you QVector.

Comment: @iam_peter, i was initially using `pop_front()`

Comment: Did you try to set [useOpenGL](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtcharts-abstractseries.html#useOpenGL-prop) to `true` for performance improvement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `beginInsertRows()` and `endInsertRows()` I've used `beginResetModel()` and `endResetModel()` which works. I assume the range for the `beginInsertRows()` is wrong and it doesn't send an update anymore, so it stops drawing. You would probably also need to call `beginRemoveRows()` I would stick with a full reset.

```
void DataModel::addData(const QPointF &point)
{
    beginResetModel();

    if (m_data.size() == 500) {
        m_data.pop_front();
        emit xMinChanged();
    }

    m_data.push_back(point);
    emit xMaxChanged();

    endResetModel();
}
```

[image]

---

**Edit:** This will also work.

```
void DataModel::addData(const QPointF &point)
{
    if (m_data.size() == 500) {
        beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), 0, 0);
        m_data.pop_front();
        endRemoveRows();
        emit xMinChanged();
    }

    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    m_data.push_back(point);
    endInsertRows();
    emit xMaxChanged();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a full reset mean a much bigger performance hit than doing a proper BeginRemoveRows({}, 0, 0)? If done before the BeginInsertRows, things should work nice

Comment: When popping front and pushing back the whole model would be dirty and trigger a full redraw?

Comment: @iam_peter. Thanks for your edit. That is getting me there but mine is still a bit janky, Are you able to post a reproducible example please? I'm emitting minChanged and valueAxis on the X axis is then `m_data[0]` while max is now `m_data(currentPoint)` but this doesn't look as smooth as yours and I just experience a jump

Comment: https://github.com/iam-peter/stackoverflow/tree/main/questions/75032636